# How to plot datetime formatted data "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"?

Tags: python, plot

I have a lot of electricity consumption data broken down on hourly basis and I try step by step getting to a ARIMA analysis, but I get stuck when trying to plot the data.

I have worked with a subset of the full dataset, but the full data can be seen here.

[data.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bo9SlmW-A8itV9w0ulDSA1mrcsisu1TK/view?usp=sharing)

In this example dates are not correctly shown on x-axis.
[image]

In this data is being shown very strangely.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide information what library you use to generate the plot? Ideally with a piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to use [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) to control the format of the date. You can use the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df = pd.read_csv('/home/damien/Downloads/data.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')
ax = df['kw'].plot(title='Power', ylabel='Power (kw)', xlabel='')
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]